# Integrating Doctrine 2 with Zend framework via Reverse Engineering

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, integration, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to integrate Zend framework with Doctrine 2 but with an existing database? All the tutorials I read constructed the "Entities" and used them to generate the tables, but I have an up and running database that could be used to generate the models.

I think there is an option to reverse engineer a database schema in Doctrine and generate the corresponding models from it. Just need a simple tutorial to show me how it's done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have information about this process [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering). It's not a bullet-proof process, so you'll probably have to adjust a few things afterwards.

Comment: yes I know about this page, but what I need is a tutorial explaining how to do the integration using reverse engineering. I have been working a lot with Doctrine 1 and I used reverse engineering in it successfully.

Comment: That is exactly what the link I gave you does. It explains how you can create Doctrine2 entity mappings from an existing database; these mappings are 80% of the work in creating the entity classes (i.e., the models) themselves. After you have these models/entities you can then start thinking about integrating them in ZF, which is a different problem altogether (although much easier, and with plenty explanations out there).

Comment: hmmm I see your point, but I'm still confused about the whole process. In Doctrine 1 I had a script that used to scan the database schema, generate the models then add them to the project. All I had to do is add Doctrine library to the library folder. However, in Doctrine 2 many things seems different. That's why I need a complete tutorial the uses reverse engineering with integration to comprehend the whole process.

Comment: My advice, do it a step at a time. First, get the yaml mappings (follow instructions in the link above); Second, generate basic Doctrine2 entities from these mappings (use doctrine tool with parameter orm:generate-entities, reference here http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#command-overview); Third, configure Doctrine2 to work with ZF (easy, just google it). Fourth, make your entities work with ZF: this part you have to code yourself, because ZF uses a loose model paradigm, so everybody does it as they see fit.